# spark structured streaming: not writing correctly

Tags: python, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am streaming meter reading records as JSON from kafka_2.11-0.10.0.1 into Spark 2.1. I switched to structured streaming; and although kafka consumer confirms incoming data, I the console and writeStream dont move. I am testing using

```
pyspark --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.1.0
```

My code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("interval") \
    .master("local[4]") \
    .getOrCreate()
schema = StructType().add("customer_id", StringType()) 
df = spark \
      .readStream \
      .format("kafka") \
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "xx.xxx.xx.xxx:9092") \
      .option("subscribe", "test") \
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
  .load() \
  .select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema).alias("parsed_value"))

query = df.writeStream \
 .option("checkpointLocation", "/user/XX/checkpoint5") \
 .format("parquet") \
 .start("/user/XX/interval5")
```

It creates the checkpoint & data directories with a 388 byte parquet file. However no streamed data is ever written.

```
$ hdfs dfs -ls interval5
drwxr-xr-x   ... interval5/_spark_metadata
-rw-r--r--   ... interval5/part-00000-0b2eb00a-c361-4dfe-a24e-9589d150a911.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   ... interval5/part-00000-e0cb12d1-9c29-4eb0-92a8-688f468a42ce.snappy.parquet
```

kafka-consumer confirms data is being shipped:

```
{"customer_id":"customer_736"}
{"customer_id":"customer_995"}
{"customer_id":"customer_1899"}
{"customer_id":"customer_35"}
```

kafka-consumer displays the streamed data.

I think I'm missing an essential step to dequeue and save the streamed rows - a day of trawling stackoverflow has not helped.
(edited to remove the references to the console; as it is not relevant).

Comment: Sorry - I garbled some of the code while anonymizing it. ignore the console line. The parquet line is 
query12 = df.writeStream.format("parquet").option("checkpointLocation", "/user/XX/checkpoint").start("/user/XX/data"). This creates the directories and writes the metadata only, but nothing else.

Comment: Fix the query with `console` first before you use `parquet`. Does the query show the output using `console` format/sink?

Comment: Remove `from_json` and use just `col("value").cast("string")` with `console` format and make sure that works. Remove layers until you hunt down the root cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same structured streaming .py code works in spark-submit, but it never processes any data using pspark; with no error message, console output or parquet data (apart from directory creation and metadata).
Go figure.

Answer (score 2):

With `.option("startingOffsets", "latest")` you should only expect messages that were published after you've started the streaming query.

So, the expected course of action is to start the streaming query and then publish messages.

> Nothing is written into the parquet files.

You will see **nothing** saved into parquet files since you used `.format("console")`. You have to change it to `parquet` and restart the query.

Comment: edit to clarify: I removed the console writeStream and corrected the parquet writeStream. This is in pyspark (not spark-submit). I presume this should work the same way.

Comment: i am trying the same as above code in spark-2.3.0. but i am getting "Exception in thread "stream execution thread for [id = 955586b4-38b3-4dcd-8fc1-4e49964789da, runId = 38606d61-2005-4bdb-9484-e840ae2b5ed8]" java.lang.AbstractMethodError". can you please help me here.

Comment: You'd be better off posting a separate question with the whole stacktrace (`AbstractMethodError`).